# Scanning through the Network

Tags: scanning, document-scanning

Our office uses a [Toshiba estudio2830c](http://business.toshiba.com/usa/product/multifunction/color-mfp/e-STUDIO2830C.html) to scan to the network and to send and receive faxes.

Most days the scanning works correctly however there are some days when it takes almost hours for a staff member to receive the scan from the machine. Sometimes the staff member never receives. 
What is the disconnect?

I have had the Toshiba Techical Team out numerous times, as well as our IT team that manages our server. Between them both, I have not been given an answer.

Comment: By 'scan to network' do you mean it drops it in a shared folder? Do the faxes work ok?